# How to SAML federate your Azure account with G Suite

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I was wondering what are your ideas about enabling SAML federated access to Azure Subscriptions by G Suite users (G Suite as IdP and Azure as SP).

I will share with you an article that I published about this topic. I'm sure I will get precious feedbacks from you!

https://medium.com/leapp-cloud/how-to-saml-federate-your-azure-account-with-g-suite-96aedc9516e6

So... what are your Azure Subscriptions access strategies, and how did you implement it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already wrote an article about this, but you could use Google Identity as your Identity provider and [add federation and authentication through Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp) following the instructions linked.

It looks like [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/24467/issue-with-saml-between-gsuite-idp-and-office-365.html) have been able to achieve this successfully as well.

You will need to [map the identities](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on) between the two.

Comment: I think the first two links describe an approach that is aligned to the one that I've already adopted. I'm gonna experiment G Suite Users provisioning through the third link you provided. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Will be interested to see your results!